# Question on the transition map of tangent bundle

Tags: smooth-manifolds

This is a follow-up question on [diffeomorphism of the bundle chart of a Tangent bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789878/diffeomorphism-of-the-bundle-chart-of-a-tangent-bundle)

I don't understand how I can write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$. Shouldn't it be $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = \sum\limits_{j}\frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$, if I were to use chain rule?

How can I see that $\frac {\partial v} {\partial x}$ and $\frac {\partial y} {\partial u}$ is zero?

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum over a repeated index is implied. This is known as the  [Einstein convention.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)

Note that the $j$ in $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$$
is otherwise a "free variable."

Comment: @Kajelad fyi I basically copied your answer here. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: I don't mind at all; in hindsight It should have been an answer rather than a comment.